# Efficiently Parsing through large amount of files

Tags: bash, parsing, parallel-processing, gnu

I need some help trying to find an efficient way to parse out the file path to a large amount of small stdout files, and creating .csv files out of them.

Example: find $PWD -name stdout

> /root/size/6/color/red/stdout
>
> /root/size/3/color/green/stdout

Running this shell script will create

> 6-red.csv
>
> 3-green.csv

This loop is working on thousands of files and I'm trying to make sure this is the correct solution.

Any kind of direction would be very helpful. Thank you!

```
dirfiles=($(find $PWD -name stdout))
for outfile in "${dirfiles[@]}"
do
   thisResult=$( cat $outfile )
   IFS='/' read -a params <<< "$outfile"

   for index in "${!params[@]}"
   do
      param=${params[index]}

      if [ "$param" = "size" ]; then
        size=${params[index+1]}
      fi

      if [ "$param" = "color"]; then
        color=${params[index+1]}
      fi

   done

echo $thisResult 1>>outputCSV/${size}-{color}.csv
done
```

Comment: Is this working? Is the question here whether this can be improved in efficiency? Are you looking for shell-specific solutions or are other tools (e.g. `awk`, `perl`, etc.) acceptable? Does it matter that this isn't safe for directories with space in the names?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to your input and output formats?

Comment: Yes this is working, but is taking a very long time to process through an increasing data set. I am looking for the most efficient method, whether it is using shell or other tools. (etc, perl, python, awk).

Comment: I have edited the post to be a little more specific. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use perlrename (prename/pren/rename):

```
# Allow ** to match dirs
shopt -s globstar
rename 's:size/::;s:color/::;s:/:-:g;s:-stdout:.csv:' **/stdout
```

Or if you want a copy:

```
find | grep stdout | parallel cp {} '{= s:[.]/::; s:size/::; s:color/::; s:/:-:g; s:-stdout:.csv: =}'
```